# What factors can affect a disk's seek time?

Tags: performance, operating-systems

sorry for the beginner question.

I am learning about how fast a disk can do its process (read/write) and move between tracks. One if the factor related to this is disk's seek time.

I am curious, in a disk, what factors in the disk itself that can affect the seek time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things:

1. The distance traveled from One track to another.
2. The head  settlement time once it reaches the correct track.
3. The rotation  delay until the sector to be read or written comes under the disk
   head.

Comment: this applies only to magnetic spindle disks

Comment: @Keltari I would say this applies to any rotational disk; HDD, CD, DVD, Floppy, Blu Ray, Etc.  Do they have holographic disks yet?